# Open3d Color Points interactively

Tags: python, colors, point-clouds, open3d

I'd like to color my points based on a sliding threshold.

I know we can do

```
depth.colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(my_numpy_array)
```

But I'd like to be able to adjust the value interactively.

I am using the python version of open3d.

Answer (score -1):

You can check the RGBD data format or pointCloud data fomat in open3D, you can construct a RGB image based on the depth value in the depth image or a list of color based on the coordinates of the list of points. In the end, you can easily construct the RGBD image or PC through

```
pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(np.array(points))
pcd.colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(np.array(colors))
```

to construct a PC or refer to http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/Basic/rgbd_image.html to construct RGBD image.